# Why is my <input> element 4px taller than it's specified height?

Tags: html, css

I put an input in a header, for testing purposes, I want the input to be as tall as the header, but when I set the input height to the same height as the header, the input is taller... so I added `margin: 0px` and `padding: 0px` to the input... but still, it's taller than the height. When I put the height of the input to 46px, it's then equal to the header, which is 50px height.

```css
.container{
    width: 96%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #05568D;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#searchId{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" id="searchId">
</div>
```

What is the reason for this? How do I correct it.

Comment: Put `border: 0`, or use `box-sizing: border-box`

Answer (score 4):

It's because of the `box-sizing` attribute.
The default `box-sizing` value is `content-box`.

> content-box gives you the default CSS box-sizing behavior. If you set an element's width to 100 pixels, then the element's content box will be 100 pixels wide, and the width of any border or padding will be added to the final rendered.

So when you give 46px in input box it's height become 50px(content:46px + border: 4px).

Put `box-sizing: border-box` in searchId.